Is it possible to edit content in the Collapsible sets without using HTML editor?
I am creating a website for grocery products,the collapsible sets will include content like: ingredients, extra descriptions, and a table of nutritional values.
I want to edit content easily in default editor mode.
I have created a template product page with Collapsible sets based on the tutorials from W3Schools.
Since in the default text editor mode all the collapsible sets are 'folded'. I am editing content directly from the HTML editor.
Is it possible to 'unfold' the content in the editor mode, so content managers can key in content without touching the code?

Sorry but... What do you mean with default editor mode? You can change whatever you want in your browser, but nobody else will see it unless you save it on the server. Or do you mean that contributors will copy code to W3Schools Tryit Editor in order to edit it? Also, the Collapsible you mention is not any standard or builin HTML component, it's just custom JavaScript code someone wrote for W3Schools.

I don't understand. Editor mode?  "unfold' the content"?  "so content managers can key in content without touching the code?"  I know how to make entries to fill in...  Not sure what you're after.

Hi @ÁlvaroGonzález, I will try again to explain what I mean ( sorry I am very new to code so I am trying my best!)
Default editor mode is the page I see when trying to edit the content of a product page on my website ( from CMS), normally we only need to type in words just like typing something in WORD doc.
Since now I make a collapsible table, the content in the collapsible table is only possible to be edited if I click on 'Show HTML' and edit. I would like to know if it's possible to edit without switching to 'show HTML' mode
Hope it helps a bit more !!

CMS is a software category and there're probably thousands of them. You need to figure out the exact product you are using and edit the to question include that information, particularly in the question tags. That way the question is discoverable by whoever's familiar with the program.
